# Is it possible not to upgrade to JDK 9 when this gets available?

Tags: java

Once the JDK9 is Generally available can we continuously blocked the upgrade? 
IF yes until when?

Currently we have an application using java pluggins, we are still working on the equivalent web application. As per news the target date for the JDK9 is March 23.

If by March 23 we are still not done can we block the JDK9 upgrade?

Comment: Java isn't Windows.

Comment: JDK updates don't usually overwrite older ones, but rather get installed along side. Besides, chances are that your plugins will continue to compile and run under JDK9.

Comment: Currently we have users that cannot access the application after upgrading their Java in their PC.

Comment: You want to prevent *your users* from upgrading to Java 9? No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can still download and install Java 5, if you really want. Nothing will compel you to upgrade to Java 9, however Oracle will eventually end support for Java 8, at which point you'll stop getting security updates. The last public release of [Java 7 was almost two years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history), for example. Any improvements to the JVM or JDK since then are only available in Java 8.

Even if you don't care about security(?!?!?) the correctness of your application will also start to falter - JDK releases contain updated timezone information, among other data that changes over time.

In general, it's going to be a lot better for you to work to solve your problem a different way that's future compatible, than to stick to legacy features that are no longer supported.

Comment: Wont Oracle force the update after certain period of time?

Comment: How would they do that, exactly?